# How to append to a list of variables in a Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, wildcard, gnu-make

I am trying to write a Makefile for the following project structure

```
/project
  Makefile
  main.cpp
  test.hpp
  /a
    s1.cpp 
    s1.hpp 
    s2.cpp 
    s2.hpp
  /b
    s1.cpp 
    s1.hpp 
    s2.cpp 
    s2.hpp
  /c
    s1.cpp 
    s1.hpp 
    s2.cpp 
    s2.hpp
```

I have 3 folders with .cpp and .hpp files, I'd like to have in the INC variable all the hpp files together

```
DIRS = ./a ./b ./c
INC = $(wildcard *.hpp) # how to have here ./a/s1.hpp ./a/s2.hpp ./b/s1.hpp ./b/s2.hpp etc...?
```

INC only grabs the .hpp files in the Makefile directory and not in the subdirectories. How to automatically specify all headers in subdirectories? Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wildcard` function takes several patterns. The `addsuffix` function appends a suffix to each word in a list. So:

```
INC = $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.hpp,$(DIRS)))
```

should do what you want. There are other ways like:

```
INC = $(foreach d,$(DIRS),$(wildcard $(d)/*.hpp))
```

or, if you have the `find` utility and want to find all `*.hpp` files, in any subdirectory at any depth (not just in `$(DIRS)`):

```
INC = $(shell find . -type f -name '*.hpp')
```

This last form may be better because you do not need to provide the list of directories.